# Can I use a metal filament on M3D Micro (or Pro)?

Tags: print-material, filled-pla

Can I use a metal filament such as Copper, Zinc Alloy, Silver filaments on M3D Micro? *The Pro hasn't come out yet but I assume it would if the Micro can since the Pro is suppose to be the improvement edition.*

An example of a metal filament that I found is this [Silver PLA 1.75mm Filament](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00T76GLWE). Here's one for [Cooper PLA 1.75mm Filament](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-plated-copper-pla-1-75mm-filament-1kg-2-2lb-for-3d-printers.html?gclid=CjwKEAjwtLO7BRDax4-I4_6G71USJAA6FjN1VDu_t4Co-u949PfHWjVL0x6BD-I-4ZLRUEij0bhWLhoCSSbw_wcB).

I would like to make small sculptures or bracelet beads/charms, and whatever else I could think of making using metal. And, I'm asking because I'm new to 3d printing, I want to learn how to work with a 3d printer and M3D is very affordable for me. *So I'm making sure before I buy*. Note that I've emailed M3D twice and I didn't get any reply.

If not M3D, can any other 3D Printer comparable to M3D do this? The MBot Mini, maybe?

Answer (score 5):

Most 3D printers that use non-proprietary filament *can* print exotic filaments, such as the ones you mention. One thing to be aware of, though, is that some of these filaments [wear down the nozzle](http://makezine.com/2015/09/11/carbon-fiber-filament-ruins-nozzles/) far more quickly than ordinary PLA, and therefore should be used with [reinforced nozzles](http://e3d-online.com/V6-nozzle-hardened-steel-3mmx0.4mm) (unless you have extra nozzles to spare). Carbon fibre and metallic filaments are generally known to increase nozzle wear, while softer alloys such as wood and bamboo generally are less abrasive.

A quick google search reveals that many people have used non-proprietary filament on the M3D Micro successfully, but be aware that using such filaments is not covered by your [warranty](https://printm3d.com/terms-of-use). If you are going to use abrasive filaments with your Micro, I would check that M3D allows you to replace the nozzle first.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that the metals are so fine and mixed in with other ingredients that you cannot tell that there is metal at all. But looks like its 100% metals.

Comment: I'm not sure that this really addresses the question of whether metal can be printed on the M3D, unless you meant to say "yes, because you can't tell there's metal so it prints like plastic" (in which case your answer wouldn't be entirely correct because of the issues raised by Tormod).

Comment: This answer might be okay if it was elaborated a bit more. My interpretation is that @Jeanie was hinting towards the idea that it is possible to technically print with "metal" filament without completely wearing down the extruder. If my interpretation is wrong, Jeanie, then please feel free to correct me and in the meantime, consider adding to your answer to avoid conversion to a comment.

Comment: I meant to say....yes you can use metal filament because it is blended into PLA at such a fine rate that you can't even tell it's in there except for the "look" as for wearing down the extruder...I don't know and I never mentioned the extruder. Nor was it mentioned in "the question"